# Action economies, two-handed weapons, and spells with Somatic components

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, actions, spell-components

This is a follow-on to [Can you cast spells with a Somatic component if you're holding a two-handed weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/can-you-cast-spells-with-a-somatic-component-if-youre-holding-a-two-handed-weap)

So, I have a spell, say Sanctuary, that is cast as a *bonus action*, yet requires Verbal and Somatic (and in this case Material, but that is taken care of by my character's holy symbol) components to cast.  Can my character take their off hand off their two-handed weapon (light crossbow) to cast this spell as the bonus action, then regrip the weapon with both hands in order to use it as the turn's regular action?  Or do they lose their regular action in order to regrip the weapon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes you can cast a Bonus Action spell and still attack with a two-handed weapon.

Taking your hand off it in the first place should not require any action expenditure - you are just letting go of something, same as if you dropped it.

Reloading is part of the attack action with a ranged weapon. To reload, you must first take one hand off the crossbow. If your hand is *already* off the crossbow due to casting, why should it take any longer?

Even with a melee weapon, drawing the weapon can be done as part of the attack action, so putting your casting hand back on it should not take any extra time.

Comment: Note that with a melee weapon, drawing the weapon as part of the attack action does still in fact use the once per round object interaction. It's a bit confusing the way they unnecessarily added this bit into the book, I think they were trying to help players along with role playing the object interactions. So you can't attack with a drawn weapon, and still have your object interaction left up. And thusly, mechanics such as the Dual Wielder Feat ability to drawn and stow two weapons instead of one are not moot.