# Can you cast a spell with a Somatic component if you're attacking with a two-handed weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components

The related question – [Can you cast spells with a Somatic component if you're holding a two-handed weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/) – says that you can cast a spell if you're **holding** a 2H weapon. The [PHB Errata](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/ph_errata) says:

> **Two-Handed (p. 147).** This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.

Although, that means if you **attack** with the weapon, both your hands are occupied. **Hence the question.** Can you cast a spell you're **attacking** with a two-handed weapon?

### An example situation

Let's say two wizards are having a squabble. Wizard 1 smacks Wizard 2 with his staff, using both hands. On his turn, Wizard 2 tries to smack Wizard 1. I assume turns happen simultaneously in D&D 5e combat. Can Wizard 1 casts Shield **as a reaction**, while both his hands are occupied in that very moment?

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53035/27377) implies you can cast a bonus action spell. But it is "especially swift" according to the PHB. What about a reaction spell?

Comment: To clarify for others who were confused like me: Is the distinction here performing the somatic component while holding a 2 handed weapon vs while attacking with a 2 handed weapon (assuming combat is simultaneous)?

Comment: It seems the OP is looking for rules on reaction-time spells while attacking with a 2h weapon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, you can cast while holding/wielding a 2-handed weapon

The specifics of reaction and bonus actions are covered by Jeremy Crawford from Sage Advice in a few separate threads. The crux is basically that there is no action economy for releasing a hand from a 2-handed weapon. Casting and fighting is not a problem for the 2-handed weapon folk.

[Using vs Carried](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/516978109342445569?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2017%2F03%2F02%2F2-weapon-casting%2F)

> Yeah, I would allow it too. A two-handed weapon needs two hands to be used, but not necessarily two to be carried.

[Reaction Castings](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/835199365375385603?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2017%2F03%2F02%2F2-weapon-casting%2F)

> Paraphrasing: He's basically saying that switching between 1 or 2 hands is a non-action.

Answer (score 2):

There are no simultaneous actions in DnD 5e. The system is not made to handle such a thing. Thus you cannot both be attacking and casting a reaction spell. Because of this the answer is the same as for the [question about holding a two-handed weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/can-you-cast-spells-with-a-somatic-component-if-youre-holding-a-two-handed-weap), which is yes, you can cast it.