# Can you draw and or throw a javelin on one or more successive turns while still using a 2-handed weapon for opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Assuming you do not have any extra attacks involved, can you start your turn holding a 2-handed weapon with one hand, use your free object interaction to draw a javelin, then throw the javelin with your attack and return your hand to your 2-handed weapon for opportunity attacks (such as granted by Polearm Master)?

The difference between this and other questions is the javelin will no longer be in your hand at the end of your turn so the meat of it is can you put your now empty hand back on the two handed weapon so you can use said weapon for opportunity attacks before your turn ends or not.

Scenario 1. As described holding 2h weapon in one hand. Draw javelin, throw javelin, place second hand on 2h weapon. Is that legal to do in one turn?

Scenario 2. If no to scenario one, would the answer change if you started your turn holding 2h weapon in one hand and javelin in the other? I’m almost positive this setup would work because your free object interaction would be grab 2h weapon with both hands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you drop one hand from a two-handed weapon to draw and use a single-handed weapon next turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135182/can-you-drop-one-hand-from-a-two-handed-weapon-to-draw-and-use-a-single-handed-w)

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Also related/possible duplicate: [Holding a longbow (or other 2H weapon) and attacking with a shortsword (or other 1H weapon)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/holding-a-longbow-or-other-2h-weapon-and-attacking-with-a-shortsword-or-other) Though this is slightly unique in that you're throwing the 1-handed weapon and then trying to grab the 2-handed weapon again with that hand.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open. The first potential dupe is about a very different scenario, where the two-handed weapon is unusable between turns. Likewise, the second potential dupe doesn't involve grabbing the two-handed weapon again in the same round. I think this is a unique question because it requires letting go with one hand, making an attack with a separate weapon, and then re-grabbing the two-handed weapon in a single turn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Holding a longbow (or other 2H weapon) and attacking with a shortsword (or other 1H weapon)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/holding-a-longbow-or-other-2h-weapon-and-attacking-with-a-shortsword-or-other)

Comment: And gm confirmed as per the answerers description and rationale. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you can draw and throw a weapon while still using a two-handed weapon for opportunity attacks

According to the [PHB Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf), you only need two hands to attack with a polearm, not to wield it.

> **Two-Handed (p. 147).**
> This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.

[Per Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/836293963979972608) (no longer official rulings, but still a strong indication of RAI), it is a non-action to switch between one and two hands:

> **@calebrus44** 27 Feb 2017
>
> He's basically saying that switching between 1 or 2 hands is a non-action.
>
> **@JeremyECrawford** 27 Feb 2017
>
> Replying to @calebrus44 @SimonsOrion @mikemearls
>
> That's correct.

This interpretation is supported in-game by two-handed weapons which use ammunition, for example the longbow; As part of the (potentially multiple) attacks, you must take a hand off the weapon to draw ammunition, then grasp it again, without using your free object interaction.

**As always, it is best to check with your GM.** As this is somewhat of a grey area in RAW, some tables may be more restrictive and rule that swapping to a two-handed hold requires your free object interaction.